# Getting the same context variable in two template blocks

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I have a django template tag that sets a context variable (it gets a random image from a model, but for this example, lets say it gets a random number)

```
{% get_random_number %}
{{ my_random_number }} <!-- outputs a random number between 1 and 10 -->
```

This works fine.

However I need to get the same 'random' number in two different blocks within my page:

```
{% block block1 %}
  {% get_random_number %}
  {{ my_random_number }} <!-- outputs a random number between 1 and 10 -->
{% endblock %}

{% block block2 %}
  {% get_random_number %}
  {{ my_random_number }} <!-- outputs a random number between 1 and 10 -->
{% endblock %}
```

This obviously doesn't work as I get two different results (unless by chance, they're the same!)

So how do you use a templatetag to set a context variable that's consistent across two template blocks?

doing this doesn't work - the context variable is limited to the block it's created in...

```
{% get_random_number %}

{% block block1 %}
  {{ my_random_number }}
{% endblock %}

{% block block2 %}
  {{ my_random_number }}
{% endblock %}
```

So.. how can I 'save' the initial result somewhere else, then recall it, if it's already been generated earlier in the call?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Probably, you can use `{% with %}` tag

```
{% with my_random_number=get_random_number %}

{% block block1 %}
  {{ my_random_number }}
{% endblock %}

{% block block2 %}
  {{ my_random_number }}
{% endblock %}

{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move your template tag logic to your view instead.  In your view you would only need to call `get_random_number` getting 1 number, and then use that in as many places as you want in your template.